# How to make LWP and HTML::TableExtract spitting out CSV with Text::CSV

Tags: perl, csv, extract, separator, lwp

I am currently working on a  little parser.

i have had very good results with the first script! This was able to run great! 
It fetches the data from the page: http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=n&a=20
(note 6142 records) - But note - the data are not separated, so the subequent work with the data is a bit difficult. Therefore i have a second script - see below!

Note - friends helped me with the both scripts. I need to introduce myself as a true novice who needs help in migration two in one. So, you see, my Perl-knowlgedge is not so elaborated that i am able to do the migration into one on my own! Any and all help would be great!

The first script: a spider and parser: it spits out the data like this:

```
lfd. Nr. Schul- nummer Schulname Straße PLZ Ort Telefon Fax Schulart Webseite
1 0401 Mädchenrealschule Marienburg, Abenberg, der Diözese Eichstätt Marienburg 1 91183  Abenberg   09178/509210  Realschulen  mrs-marienburg.homepage.t-online.de 
2 6581 Volksschule Abenberg (Grundschule) Güssübelstr. 2 91183  Abenberg   09178/215 09178/905060 Volksschulen  home.t-online.de/home/vs-abenberg 
3 6913 Mittelschule Abenberg  Güssübelstr. 2 91183  Abenberg   09178/215 09178/905060 Volksschulen  home.t-online.de/home/vs-abenberg 
4 0402 Johann-Turmair-Realschule Staatliche Realschule Abensberg Stadionstraße 46 93326  Abensberg   09443/9143-0,12,13 09443/914330 Realschulen  www.rs-abensberg.de
```

But i need to separate the data: with commas or someting like that!

And i have a second script. This part can do the CSV-formate. i want to ombine it with the spider-logic. But first lets have a look at the first script: with the great spider-logic.

see the code that is appropiate:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use HTML::TableExtract;
    use LWP::Simple;
    use Cwd;
    use POSIX qw(strftime);
    my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
    my $total_records = 0;
    my $suchbegriffe = "e";
    my $treffer = 50;
    my $range = 0;
    my $url_to_process = "http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=";
    my $processdir = "processing";
    my $counter = 50;
    my $displaydate = "";
    my $percent = 0;

    &workDir();
    chdir $processdir;
    &processURL();
    print "\nPress <enter> to continue\n";
    <>;
    $displaydate = strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', localtime);
    open OUTFILE, ">webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt";
    &processData();
    close OUTFILE;
    print "Finished processing $total_records records...\n";
    print "Processed data saved to $ENV{HOME}/$processdir/webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt\n";
    unlink 'processing.html';
    die "\n";

    sub processURL() {
    print "\nProcessing $url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range\n";
    getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'tempfile.html') or die 'Unable to get page';

       while( <tempfile.html> ) {
          open( FH, "$_" ) or die;
          while( <FH> ) {
             if( $_ =~ /^.*?(Treffer <b>)(d+)( - )(d+)(</b> w+ w+ <b>)(d+).*/ ) {
                $total_records = $6;
                print "Total records to process is $total_records\n";
                }
             }
             close FH;
       }
       unlink 'tempfile.html';
    }

    sub processData() {
       while ( $range <= $total_records) {
          getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'processing.html') or die 'Unable to get page';
          $te->parse_file('processing.html');
          my ($table) = $te->tables;
          for my $row ( $table->rows ) {
             cleanup(@$row);
             print OUTFILE "@$row\n";
          }
          $| = 1; 
          print "Processed records $range to $counter";
          print "\r";
          $counter = $counter + 50;
          $range = $range + 50;
          $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
       }
    }

    sub cleanup() {
       for ( @_ ) {
          s/s+/ /g;
       }
    }

    sub workDir() {
    # Use home directory to process data
    chdir or die "$!";
    if ( ! -d $processdir ) {
       mkdir ("$ENV{HOME}/$processdir", 0755) or die "Cannot make directory $processdir: $!";
       }
    }
```

But as this-above script-unfortunatley does not take care for the separators i have had to take care for a method, that does look for separators. In order to get the data (output) separated.

So with the separation i am able to work with the data - and store it in a mysql-table.. or do something else...So here [below] are the bits - that work out the csv-formate Note - i want to put the code below into the code above - to combine the spider-logic of the above mentioned code with the logic of outputting the data in CSV-formate.
where to set in the code Question: can we identify this point to migrate the one into the other... !? 
That would be amazing... I hope i could make clear what i have in mind...!? Are we able to use the benefits of the both parts (/scripts ) migrating them into one?

So the question is: where to set in with the CSV-Script into the script (above)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Text::CSV;

my $html= get 'http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=a&a=20';
$html =~ tr/\r//d;     # strip carriage returns
$html =~ s/&nbsp;/ /g; # expand spaces

my $te = new HTML::TableExtract();
$te->parse($html);

my @cols = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    phone
    type
    website
);

my @fields = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    street
    postal
    town
    phone
    fax
    type
    website
);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 });

foreach my $ts ($te->table_states) {
    foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {

        #  trim leading/trailing whitespace from base fields
        s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// for @$row;

        # load the fields into the hash using a "hash slice"
        my %h;
        @h{@cols} = @$row;

        # derive some fields from base fields, again using a hash slice
        @h{qw/name street postal town/} = split /\n+/, $h{name};
        @h{qw/phone fax/} = split /\n+/, $h{phone};

        #  trim leading/trailing whitespace from derived fields
        s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// for @h{qw/name street postal town/};

        $csv->combine(@h{@fields});
        print $csv->string, "\n";
    }
}
```

The thing is that i have had very good results with the first script! It fetches the data from the page: http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=n&a=20
(note 6142 records) - But note - the data are not separated...!

And i have a second script. This part can do the CSV-formate. i want to combine it with the spider-logic.

where is the part to insert?  I look forward to any and all help.

if i have to be more precice - just let me know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have entered a complete script, I'll assume you want critique of the whole thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use HTML::TableExtract;
    use LWP::Simple;
    use Cwd;
    use POSIX qw(strftime);
    my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
```

Since you only use `$te` in one block, why are you declaring and initializing it in this outer scope? The same question applies to most of your variables -- try to declare them in the innermost scope possible.

```
    my $total_records = 0;
    my $suchbegriffe = "e";
    my $treffer = 50;
```

In general, english variable names will enable you to collaborate with far more people than german names. I understand german, so I understand the intent of your code, but most of SO doesn't.

```
    my $range = 0;
    my $url_to_process = "http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=";
    my $processdir = "processing";
    my $counter = 50;
    my $displaydate = "";
    my $percent = 0;

    &workDir();
```

Don't use `&` to call subs. Just call them with `workDir;`. It hasn't been necessary to use `&` since 1994, and it can lead to a nasty gotcha because `&callMySub;` is a special case which doesn't do what you might think, while `callMySub;` does the Right Thing.

```
    chdir $processdir;
    &processURL();
    print "\nPress <enter> to continue\n";
    <>;
    $displaydate = strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', localtime);
    open OUTFILE, ">webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt";
```

Generally lexical filehandles are preferred these days: `open my $outfile, ">file";` Also, you should check for errors from open or `use autodie;` to make open die on failure.

```
    &processData();
    close OUTFILE;
    print "Finished processing $total_records records...\n";
    print "Processed data saved to $ENV{HOME}/$processdir/webdata_for_$suchbegriffe\_$displaydate.txt\n";
    unlink 'processing.html';
    die "\n";

    sub processURL() {
    print "\nProcessing $url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range\n";
    getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'tempfile.html') or die 'Unable to get page';

       while( <tempfile.html> ) {
          open( FH, "$_" ) or die;
          while( <FH> ) {
             if( $_ =~ /^.*?(Treffer <b>)(d+)( - )(d+)(</b> w+ w+ <b>)(d+).*/ ) {
                $total_records = $6;
                print "Total records to process is $total_records\n";
                }
             }
             close FH;
       }
       unlink 'tempfile.html';
    }

    sub processData() {
       while ( $range <= $total_records) {
          getstore("$url_to_process$suchbegriffe&a=$treffer&s=$range", 'processing.html') or die 'Unable to get page';
          $te->parse_file('processing.html');
          my ($table) = $te->tables;
          for my $row ( $table->rows ) {
             cleanup(@$row);
             print OUTFILE "@$row\n";
```

This is the line to change if you want to put commas in separating your data. Look at the [join](http://p3rl.org/join) function, it can do what you want.

```
          }
          $| = 1; 
          print "Processed records $range to $counter";
          print "\r";
          $counter = $counter + 50;
          $range = $range + 50;
          $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
       }
```

It's *very* strange to initialize `$te` at the end of the loop instead of the beginning. It's much more idiomatic to declare and initialize `$te` at the top of the loop.

```
    }

    sub cleanup() {
       for ( @_ ) {
          s/s+/ /g;
```

Did you mean `s/\s+/ /g;`?

```
       }
    }

    sub workDir() {
    # Use home directory to process data
    chdir or die "$!";
    if ( ! -d $processdir ) {
       mkdir ("$ENV{HOME}/$processdir", 0755) or die "Cannot make directory $processdir: $!";
       }
    }
```

I haven't commented on your second script; perhaps you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: hello Philip - many many thanks for the hints. Great to see such - in-depth-going critique! I will walk trough and have a look. It is great to see you helping me to code better. Many many thanks.  It is a great pleasure to be here!

Comment: @ Philip: regarding your ideas concerning the second script: i want to migrate the both. Can you (or someone else) give me some tips how to do both scripts in one... As being the novice - i need a helping hand here.. - all hints and tips greatly appreciated. zero

Comment: @zero If you have found this answer useful, please upvote it. That's the stackoverflow way of saying "thanks".

Comment: hi Philip. this answer was more than useful. Can  you  give me some concrete hints to migrate the both scripts. Note - friends helped me with the scripts. So, you see, my Perl-knowlgedge is not so elaborated that i am able to do the migration into one on my own! Any and all help would be great! -greetings zero

Comment: “Generally lexical filehandles are preferred these days: `open my $outfile, ">file";`”: also use three-argument open: `open my $outfile, '>', $file;`.

Comment: hello Phillip-Potter - many many thanks for he tips regarding the creating of csv-output. This is very very helpful. Thx again